# Ruby: Way to change <div> visibility, avoiding JavaScript

Tags: ruby, sinatra, haml, sass

I am looking for a nice way to change the visibility of an HTML div.

The probably most common way to do this, is by using JavaScript, since it can manipulate my DOM. In my current project, I prefer not to use any JavaScript, so here is my question:

Is there another way to solve this, by using technologies like Ruby or Sass?

I am using in my project **Ruby** + the **Sinatra** Framework, as well as **Haml** and **Sass**.

Comment: I know the JS way would be:
`      ... {
         document.getElementById("visible").style.visibility = "hidden";
       } ...
`

Comment: Do you want to do it dynamically, after the user has loaded the page, or while the page is being served? If it's after the page has been served and the browser is displaying it, then this isn't a Ruby question, it's purely JavaScript.

Comment: Javascript will not manipulate your stylesheet but the dom tree loaded in the browser. Without using javascript you can use sessions and reload page, letting the display of the div logic at server side.

Comment: I would like to have it after the page has been loaded. (but without using JavaScript)

Comment: Thanks Eric. That sounds like a good way to do.

Comment: After the page has loaded and without using javascript will not be possible unless you refresh your page every x seconds ...

Comment: `display: none` is usually the preferred way of hiding an element as it completely removes the element instead of leaving a gaping hole like `visibility: hidden` does.  There *is* an element in HTML5 (details) that has a show/hide behavior, but it should only be used if it is appropriate semantic-wise (support is poor at the moment: Chrome/Safari only).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure with HAML syntax. Whether the below fit for you need?

```
- if hide_div?
  %div {:style=> "display:none;"}
- else
  %div {:style=> "display:block;"}
- end
```